# Função realpath() não aceita variável

Tags: php

Galera, quando ponho isto:

```
$rootPath = realpath("/home/687_332_0/332");
echo $rootPath;
```

O exemplo acima irá imprimir: 687_332_0/332 (*FUNCIONA!*)

No entanto, quando ponho o que está abaixo, **o echo não funciona**:

```
$rootPath = realpath("/home/".$folder1."/".$folder2);
ou $rootPath = realpath('/home/'.$folder1.'/'.$folder2);
ou $rootPath = realpath("/home/$folder1/$folder2");

ou o mesmo processo com essas variáveis convertidas com strval() ou (string)
$caminho1 = strval($folder1);
$caminho2 = (string)$folder2;

echo $rootPath;
```

O exemplo acima irá imprimir: *NADA!*

Por que isso acontece e como o resolvo?

Comment: Poderia verificar se ao acessar essa pasta o código php tem privilegios para isso?

Comment: Tem sim. Ta tudo ok.

Comment: No exemplo que você está usando, `$folder1` e `$folder2` têm que valores? Essas variávels podem possivelmente ter caracteres estranhos como espaços, acentos, símbolos especiais, …?

Comment: 687_332_0 e 332, conforme está na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um pequeno esclarecimento sobre a função `realpath`: A mesma retornará `FALSE` caso o caminho da `pasta` ou `arquivo` não exista.

Exemplo:

```
var_dump(realpath('nao_existe/essa_pasta')); // bool(false)
```

Creio que a maneira mais apropriada para montar o caminho do `path` seria:

```
$rootPath = "/home/".$folder1."/".$folder2;

if (! is_dir($rootPath)) {
  // Faça alguma coisa se essa parta não existir
}

// ... Continua o código
```